# Using SimMetrics Java Function on Mathematica

Tags: java

I would like to know if it's possible to use/install [this java library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/) on Mathematica. This library, named SimMetrics, has a lot of string similarity functions that I would like to test.

Here is the list of functions:

> Levenstein, NeedlemanWunch, SmithWaterman, SmithWatermanGotoh,
> SmithWatermanGotohWindowedAffine, Jaro, JaroWinkler,
> ChapmanLengthDeviation, ChapmanMeanLength, QGramsDistance,
> BlockDistance, CosineSimilarity, DiceSimilarity, EuclideanDistance,
> JaccardSimilarity, MatchingCoefficient, MongeElkan,
> OverlapCoefficient.

I have no knowledge on Java and use a MAC. A thought in [Leonid Java Reloader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/), but it's a complete .jar file, not a small class.

### Update

I download the simmetrics_jar_v1_6_2_d07_02_07.jar from the link above, saved it on notebook directory and tryed:

```
Needs["JLink`"]
ReinstallJava[ClassPath->"/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/:"<>NotebookDirectory[]<>"simmetrics_jar_v1_6_2_d07_02_07.jar"]
```

Now I have to use LoadJavaClass? How can a list the available classes?

If I unzip the .jar file, the classes are inside this folder:
uk/ac/shef/wit/simmetrics/similaritymetrics/

for example: Levenshtein.class

Comment: Many of these distance functions are built in to Mathematica as well, mostly with the same names.

Comment: Given that you could do it with .NET dlls, I'd say its also possible with Java libraries. Have you tried following this?
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/JLink/tutorial/CallingJavaFromMathematica.html

Comment: tks @Jonie, it was a begin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at [this](https://github.com/Simmetrics/simmetrics/blob/master/src/uk/ac/shef/wit/simmetrics/similaritymetrics/LevenshteinTest.java) it is easy to figure out what to do:

c = LoadJavaClass[
      "uk.ac.shef.wit.simmetrics.similaritymetrics.Levenshtein"]

Then

```
Constructors@c
```

and

```
Methods@c
```

will get you going. I tried things on Windows, but it should work on Mac alike:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I just want to add a couple remarks to Rolf's excellent answer. I want to discourage the use of an idiom like `ReinstallJava[ClassPath->NotebookDirectory[]]` for modifying the Java classpath. `ReinstallJava` is a destructive operation that might impact other J/Link-using packages currently in use on your system. Instead, use `AddToClassPath["some dir containing jar files"]`. The Simmetrics library also has a full set of JavaDocs that you can download separately from the site. That type of documentation is indispensable when tinkering with a library via J/Link.